# Decipher the message $2081\ 2182$ knowing that it was encrypted using the RSA system with the key $(2537, 13)$

Tags: cryptography

Decipher the message $2081 \ 2182$ knowing that it was encrypted using the RSA system with the key $(2537, 13).$

$(2537, 13)$ is a public key $(n, e)$. To decipher the message I need to find the inverse modulo of e which is d:

$$d= e^{-1} \mod (p-1)(q-1)$$

I have $n$, how can I find $p$ and $q$?

Comment: If I told you $n=21$, could you figure out $p$ and $q$?

Comment: No lol, so this how rsa works?

Comment: OK, so go back to your notes.

Comment: p = 3 and q = 7? Both are prime numbers

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: So for my current question/exercise. I take any prime numbers p and q which gives me 2537 when I multiply them? Like p=43 and q=59?

Comment: Yes.  It won't be "any" prime pair:  the factors are unique.

Comment: Ok thanks Randall, I'm still kinda lost, but I'll try to understand it

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I'm guessing because you've shown no background or efforts.  It reads like a "here's my homework" problem.

Comment: No it's not my homework problem trust me on this. I can't really start the exercise without knowing how to start it, I'm not asking for you guys to do it for me

Comment: Thanks for the edit Kenta!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a realistic $n$ you cannot find the primes $p$ and $q$ from $n=pq$, that's what makes RSA secure..

This is a very small $n$ so here we can use algorithms to find $p$ and $q$ that are fast enough.

An online resource like [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+2537) can do it easily (you could easily write a little program to to do trial division as well), and gives $p=43$, $q=59$ as the solution. Now you try and do the rest.

Comment: The result will be $1819$ $1415$, some encoding of the alphabet, maybe?

Comment: Looks like 'STOP' to me.